# Why textFieldShouldReturn delegate cannot be drag and drop as @IBAction?

Tags: ios, swift

drag and drop is convenient, I can drop and drop some action from a `UITextField` like below

[image]

But why `textFieldShouldReturn` must have only to implement `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol?

Comment: Because that event isn't an action, it is part of the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol.  It is part of the delegate protocol because the function has to return `true` or `false` while `@IBAction` functions return `void`

Comment: Does the main difference between `UITextFieldDelegate` with `@IBAction` is have return value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of textFieldShouldReturn method is a part of the uitextfield delegate protocol, so you can not use this method as an IBAction and IBAction method void return value.